# PHP: Help looping through array while key value != NULL

Tags: php

I have an array of all "categories" and their parents, and I would like to make a separate array of just the parents of the specified category.

Example:

```
$categories = Array ( 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 1 
    [CatName] => Recipes 
    [CatParent] => ) 
  [2] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 2 
    [CatName] => Desserts 
    [CatParent] => 1 ) 
  [3] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 3 
    [CatName] => Cakes 
    [CatParent] => 2 ) 
  [4] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 4 
    [CatName] => Main Course
    [CatParent] => 1 ) 
)
```

So, how do I loop through this array to find all the parents of "cakes" (ID of 2)? Keep looping through all the parent categories until that category has no parent (NULL). Something which would return an array like:

```
$categories = Array ( 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 1 
    [CatName] => Recipes 
    [CatParent] => ) 
  [2] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 2 
    [CatName] => Desserts 
    [CatParent] => 1 ) 
  [3] => Array ( 
    [ID] => 3 
    [CatName] => Cakes 
    [CatParent] => 2 ) 
)
```

Notice all the array keys match the category ID already, and category ID 3 has a parent of category 2, and category 2 has a parent of category 1.

If I wanted to find the parents of category ID 4, it would return an array with category 4 and category 1.

Comment: Using loops and maybe some recursion; where's the  code you've tried?

Comment: @Terminus I know I need to do this in a loop, I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution** to your problem would be to use a function like this:

```
function get_parent_categories($category_array, $category){
    $cat_id = null;
    $parent_category_array = array();
    foreach($category_array as $key => $cat){
        if($cat['CatName'] == $category){
            $cat_id = isset($cat['CatParent']) ? $cat['CatParent'] : null;
            $parent_category_array[] = $category_array[$key];
            break;
        }
    }
    while($cat_id != null){
        $parent_category_array[] = $category_array[$cat_id];
        $cat_id = $category_array[$cat_id]['CatParent'];
    }
    return $parent_category_array;
}
```

Now call `get_parent_categories()` function in the following way,

```
// In this function call, $categories is your original category array
$parent_category_array = get_parent_categories($categories, 'Cakes');

// display $parent_category_array array
var_dump($parent_category_array);
```

---

Here's a [**live demo**](https://eval.in/695211):